How to reauthenticate aws cognito user in vue with persisted state?
I have a Vuejs app which runs on vue 2.7.14 and uses latest amazon-cognito-identity-js npm package.
Using a dashboard theme from Creative Tim where I have been implementing business logic.
I use vuex to manage state along with vuex-persistedstate to save state of app on refresh of the page.
I have spin up aws cognito user pool where I manage all the users for the app. Everything seems fine, but when I want to implement functionality for update details I face an issue.
First I want to pull the user's attributes to prefill the details form, but for that I again need to authenticate user through cognitoUser.authenticateUser( function, because the following cognitoUser.getUserAttributes( requires to be called on an authenticated user. If I dont do that I get error "User is not authenticated"
The problem is that I dont want to ask user to re-enter the password again and also I don't want to store its password in state in order to call the authenticateUser function again on update detail page, which would be a big security issue...
How am I able to update user details otherwise?
Googled all possible articles, read documentation. Tried to think about diferent approaches.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
